# Refresh page after a database entry without Javascript's setTimeout()

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, messenger

Isn't there a way where I can refresh the page right after a database new entry WITHOUT using Javascript *setTimeout* or *setInterval*?

Isn't there an AJAX function to do so? Or maybe a MySql function?

The only way is keep checking the database all the time?
Doesn't it spend too much of the server?

My page will work like a Messenger.

Comment: I love looking at all these downvoted questions because they're like rubick's cubes... so what are you saying? just look into jquery $.ajax or at least provide a sample of your code.

Comment: @KaiQing dindn't get the rubik's cube joke, and neither the downvote.
And also I don't have a single code line, I don't know where to start.

Comment: The whole idea of AJAX is to avoid refreshing the page. Do you mean update and not refresh?

Comment: ok then - first, set timeout and set interval have nothing to do with databases UNLESS you use an ajax call to update a database via some server side scripting language like php. Still, timeout and interval would be your choice and not required. Look at TJ below. If you want to try something cool, check out node.js for messenger systems like chatting. the rubicks cube joke just means that it is a puzzle reading many of these questions that dont even make sense after you read them over and over again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand that what happens on the server and what happens on the client are completely separated, and while the client has a straight-forward way to contact the *server*, the converse is not true. There's no way any MySQL function could possibly refresh the browser on the *client* machine.

So polling (with ajax or similar) is frequently how this is done. However, it's not the *only* way. There are various ["Comet" techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29), and of course the new [web sockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) initiative.

Comment: and I recommend node.js just because we worked with it recently and it was very interesting as well as fast. It also looks like it might have an uprising in desired code options for clients, so it is good to know if you're doing this for a living.